# .NET WebBrowser control and "Delete browsing history on exit" setting in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, session, webbrowser-control

Our application includes a browser pane, using .NET WebBrowser control, to access a local web server serving PHP pages.  Users usually keep it running all day.

If they concurrently use IE and close it while our application is running, and the "Delete browsing history on exit" settings is checked, our WebBrowser control loses its PHP session.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Which version of IE is installed on the machine in question? This *shouldn't* be happening as a general rule, but there have been several bugs in this area over the years.

Comment: I think the bug we had today was IE9.  I can reproduce it with IE10 on my machine.
In both cases we told the WebBrowser - which defaults to IE7 by default - to use a newer version of IE by setting the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`